# How to copy file from docker container to host in jenkins pipeline sh script

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

not long ago when I was producing my test environment, I wanted to copy the file that is made during run jenkins in workspace. I wanted to copy using the command:

```
sudo docker cp container-id:/path/filename.txt ~/Desktop/filename.txt
```

The command works fine in the console but if I want to call it in pipeline jenkins script like this:

```
sh """
#!/bin/bash
sudo docker cp ${dockername}:/home/jenkins/workspace/Knife/Component_version.txt /data/test/source/Component_version.txt
"""
```

I get the message:

```
+ sudo docker cp d13eed950bad
"docker cp" requires exactly 2 arguments.
See 'docker cp --help'.

Usage:  docker cp [OPTIONS] CONTAINER:SRC_PATH DEST_PATH|-
    docker cp [OPTIONS] SRC_PATH|- CONTAINER:DEST_PATH

Copy files/folders between a container and the local filesystem
```

I see that the container ID is substituted, but I don't see the rest of the command, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is initially running the container?  If you're using Jenkins's Docker support, it bind-mounts the workspace directory into the container, so you can just copy the file without doing anything Docker-specific.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `dockername` has a new line character at the end. You have to trim it.

Comment: Do you have an idea how to trim it, to get the id of the container I use the command:

dockername = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'hostname')

Comment: `dockername = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'hostname').trim()`